# PIC MCU: Using pointers to alter output

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

so I've been trying to create a circuit with a PIC16F917, a button, and three LED's, where upon a button press the LED output changes, like the button press cycles through different modes. I've been trying to do this utilising pointers, in a way like a multiplexer, where the value of an integer depicts the certain output mode (interpreted by `outputconfig()`), and the push of a button increments that integer by 1; but don't really know what's going wrong.

Also, why does XC8 say upon the build, that the use of "delay()" and "outputconfig()" within main() is a "function declared an implicit int"? And why does it still work?

Any help and/or guidance would be much appreciated. Below is the code I am working with. Thankyou!

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic16f917.h>
#include "configbits.h"
#include "definitions.h"

int value;
int *output;
int result;

int main()
{
    TRISEbits.TRISE0=1;

    TRISDbits.TRISD5=0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD6=0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD7=0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(1==IN1)
        {
            delay();
            if(1==IN1)
            {
                output=&value+1;
                result=*output;
                outputconfig();
            }
        }
    }
}

int delay()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++){}
}

int outputconfig()
{
    if(0==value)
    {
        OUT1=1;
        OUT2=0;
        OUT3=0;
    }
    if(1==value)
    {
        OUT1=0;
        OUT2=1;
        OUT3=0;
    }
    if(2==value)
    {
        OUT1=0;
        OUT2=0;
        OUT3=1;
    }
    else
    {
        NOP();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your return type is an int, but you aren't returning anything. Change it to void delay ()

Comment: What does the & and * symbols mean when dealing with pointers? What do you think they do?

Comment: put  int outputconfig(); int delay(); above main()

Comment: @VigneshVicky that seems more like a best practise vs functional. I don't think there is any issue with placement of functions

Comment: @efox29 if we define function below main, need to initialize the function above main() ,is that wrong

Comment: @VigneshVicky, we need to *declare* the function before we use it (not "initialize" it). We can *define* the function anywhere: before or after where its used, or even in another compilation unit.

Comment: @efox29: It's not best practice - its functional. An undeclared function is assumed to return `int` even if it does not. In this case he's lucky that the compiler's assumption is correct. But if one of the functions return `float` or a pointer or anything that's not `int` then it's a bug waiting to happen. Either use the function after the function definition or declare the function prototype before using. C allows programs that don't do either to compile but it may or may not result in a correct program.

Comment: I see no button debouncing....Once the rest of the program works it's possible this will cycle through the modes 10's of times with every button press.

Comment: @Spoon I tries to avoid that problem with the delay() and nested "if" statement

Comment: @slebetman was referring to placement of functions and not return type

Comment: @efox29: Yes, placement of functions determines return type. If you place main on top like in the OP then the compiler will ALWAYS ASSUME the return type of your functions is `int` even if the function returns `float` or `struct*`.

Comment: @slebetman that doesn't make sense. If I place a void foo() function before or after main(), why would the compiler assume   that it has a return type ?

Comment: @efox29: Yes, it doesn't make sense. The compiler assume that the return type is `int` because the standard says it can. That's why I say it's not merely "best practice". That is to say, it is not opinion. It is fact that placing main on top is inviting bugs.

Comment: @efox29: If you turn on all your compiler warnings (-Wall) than you'll see that it warns you that it's assuming your `foo()` returns `int` even though you know it does not. The standard doesn't mandate this behavior. It just says compilers are allowed to do it.

Comment: @slebetman learned something new. Appreciate the info. Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482887/a-function-with-an-int-or-void-return-type-can-be-called-before-declaring-and-de and I understand what you were saying now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't initialising value or result - in fact although you are assigning a value to result with: *result=*output;* you never use result again so this line is completely redundant.
this line: *output=&value+1;* says take the address of value, add 1 to it (the location of the place after value ???) and then make output points to it

I think what you meant to do was:

```
output = &value;    // do this once before the loop to make output point at value
   // or you could initialise it when you declare it like this:
int *output = &value ;

*output = *output+1 // in the loop. increase 'value'
```

comments by others are correct regarding function declarations

Comment: So I place `int *output = &value;` at the top with the other declared `int`'s and `*output = *output+1` within the `if` statement?

Comment: yes. declaring the pointer and initializing to actually point at something is good practice.